# $\frac{(x - 2)^2}{2}-\frac{(x + 1)}{3} = (x - 3)^3$

Tags: functions, polynomials

So, I'm working on my polynomial functions exercises, and all goes well, until I reach this one. Somehow, somewhere, I seem to always be doing something wrong and not get to the desired result. My course says it should be $2$. It's not always the most reliable book, but as I myself can't think of a better solution, I'm going to assume it's right and ask you guys for some help. Just don't hold me accountable if it isn't.

This is the exercise:

> Solve the equation. Follow the following steps:
>   1. Put all factors on the left and equate to $0$.
>   2. Solve the brackets, reduce and sort the factors.
>   3. Factor to the second degree using known methods (if impossible, solve graphically).
>   4. Equate each factor to $0$ separately and solve the equation.

I'm sorry if anything in my formulation is unclear[I've translated the mathematical lingo from Dutch].

And then here's the specific exercise:

> $$\frac{(x - 2)^2}{2}-\frac{(x + 1)}{3} = (x - 3)^3$$

I tried solving like this:
Step 1:
$$\frac{(x - 2)^2}{2} - \frac{(x + 1)}{3} - (x + 3)^3 = 0$$
Step 2.1:
$$\frac{(x² - 4x + 4)}{2} - \frac{x}{3} - \frac{1}{3} - (x³ + 9x² + 27x + 27) = 0  $$
That's where I get lost. Though I'm not entirely sure of the first two steps. My solution for step $2.2$ would be:
$$\frac{x^2}{2} - 2x + 2 - \frac{x}{3} - \frac{1}{3} - x³ - 9x² - 27x - 27 = 0 $$
But after this, I have no idea what to do.

Please help me out here! My textbook doesn't offer explanations to solutions, so any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move everything from one side to the other

$$\frac12 (x-2)^2 - \frac13 (x+1) = (x-3)^3 $$

which implies that
$$\frac12 (x-2)^2 - \frac13 (x+1) - (x-3)^3 = 0 $$
(You made a small mistake by changing the sign within the bracket of the last term.)

Your method description says that you can solve it graphically. If you plot the function
$$f(x) :=  \frac12 (x-2)^2 - \frac13 (x+1) - (x-3)^3$$
you will note that there is a root around $x\approx 2$. Indeed, we can test this and if you calculate it you will find that $f(2) = 0$.

Given that $x = 2$ is a root. We know that $x-2$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Using [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) we can find that
$$f(x) = -\frac16(x-2)(6x^2-45x+86). $$

Therefore, one root is $x = 2$ and the last two can be found by solving
$$6x^2-45x+86 = 0$$
which can be solved by the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). (The roots of the last quadratic will [not be real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). Therefore, there is only one real root, namely $x=2$.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just one more question, if that's okay. If you were to solve this problem without the graphics, how would you solve the equation for the root to be used as the a in (x +/- a)?

Comment: @Lila There are general ways to solve any cubic (third degree) polynomial, however these are quite impractical, and I don't believe you'll learn them. Honestly, in practice, I would simply make a few integer guesses such as $x = 0$, $1$, $-1$, $2$, $-2$, ..., $5$, $-5$. Testing some of these will allow you to find any obvious integer solutions. If you find any you can use the method I showed by using polynomial long division. If you don't find any integer solutions, then it becomes somewhat harder...

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it like this in the future.

Comment: @Lila If you think your question has been answered, you can consider marking the answer with the tick (✓, just by the up/down vote arrows). Of course, you are welcome to wait if better answers come along. (The only reason I address this is that this site prefers to have answered questions marked as answered.)

Comment: The [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) can help you make some educated guesses at a factorization, especially for contrived exercises, which tend to factor into reasonably nice terms.